# scroll bar of data grid view is visible but not working in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

When I run my app using visual studio, scroll bar of data grid view is working fine. But when I run same app using executable file, scroll bar is visible but not able to scroll and app is displaying not responding.
Actually I'm getting data from serial port and adding to the data grid view using data grid view 's invoke function.

//code snippet

```
dgvLog.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
    gvLog.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
    dgvLog.DataSource = bs;
    dgvLog.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;

});

MessageBox.Show("Added to data grid view");
```

Data is being added to the data grid view but both horizontal and vertical scroll bar is stuck, cannot scroll. It's not showing message box after invoke is finished.

Comment: I think your code is inside some kind of loop. Maybe trying to read data from serial port and thats why its not responding. Please share some of the code how you are reading data form serial port. It's very hard to help without knowing anything from your app.

Comment: you should post your code to give an idea. It is not possible to predict what is going on in your code.

Comment: Yaa, you are right code is inside loop to get data from the serial port, but how is it working when I directly run from visual studio.

Comment: @Apurva I think you should add your reader part to a different thread then UI(main ) thread. That should free Up your UI thread to let it scroll for you.

Answer (score 0):

set the data grid view property **AutoSizeRowsMode** to **AllCells**.